# Qual a diferença entre bindParam e bindValue?

Tags: php, pdo

Qual a diferença entre [PDOStatement::bindParam()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php) e [PDOStatement::bindValue()?](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Diferenças no recebimento de valores:

Conforme [rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91/rray) citou:

> No bindParam() o argumento esperado é uma referência (variável ou constante) e não pode ser um tipo primitivo como uma string ou número solto, retorno de função/método. Já bindValue() pode receber referências e valores como argumento.

```
$stmt->bindParam(':v1', 10); // Inválido
$stmt->bindParam(':v1', getValor()); // Inválido
```

### Diferenças em `PDOStatement::execute()`

> Com **bindParam**, ao contrário de **bindValue**, a variável
>   está vinculada com uma referência e só será avaliada no momento que
>   PDOStatement::execute() é chamado.

**Com bindParam:**

```
$sex = 'male';
$s = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name FROM students WHERE sex = :sex');
$s->bindParam(':sex', $sex);
$sex = 'female';
$s->execute(); // Executado quando $sex = 'female'
```

**Com bindValue:**

```
$sex = 'male';
$s = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name FROM students WHERE sex = :sex');
$s->bindValue(':sex', $sex);
$sex = 'female';
$s->execute(); // Executado quando $sex = 'male'
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/what-is-the-difference-between-bindparam-and-bindvalue/)

Comment: Bons exemplos comparativos. +1

Comment: qual a vantagem na diferença do execute()?

Answer (score 8):

No `bindParam()` o argumento esperado é uma referência(variável ou constante) não pode ser um tipo primitivo como uma string ou número solto, retorno de função/método. `bindValue()` pode receber referências e valores como argumento, basicamente é isso.

O código abaixo retorna o erro:

> Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in

```
$stmt->bindParam(':v1', 10); //inválido
$stmt->bindParam(':v1', getValor()); //inválido
```

Comment: Seria legal citar um exemplo de quando e porque usar `bindParam`, por exemplo: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#example-1006 :) +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, bem [isso](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1179924/1342547) que eu estava vendo

Comment: Parece um boa explicação, acredito que se incrementar a tua resposta e adicionar um exemplo ira ficar muito boa a resposta.

Comment: Preciso testar, não uso sp quase, haha em 80% dos casos vc vai usar `bindValue()`.

Comment: Ta mais pra 90% kk! Isso ae, ate amanha :)

Comment: Acho que a minha ficou mais ou menos... juntei sua resposta também..

Comment: @RowAraujo, vou dar uma editada ainda so preciso de um tempo p faze as sp, coisa que não uso muito.

Answer (score 7):

Veja esse `SELECT` que uso, pelo menos aqui é um exemplo real e comumente usado, conforme solicitou:

O **bindParam** sempre uso com variareis se usar uma valor tipo 'nome usuário' no lugar da variável vai dar erro pq ele não aceita valor, e o **bindValue** é o inverso eu uso o valor mesmo `'nome do usuário'` ,`1235456`. Eu entendo assim **bindParam** parâmetros por referencia usa variável, **bindValue** valores mesmo direto sem uso de variável. Posso não estar certo em alguns pontos mas espero ajudar a clarear um pouco.

```
$usuario ='fulano';
$senha = '123456';
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nome_banco','','');
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :user AND senha = :pass ");
$query->bindParam(':user', $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
#Uso o bindParam quando uso variáveis conforme acima.

$query->bindValue(':pass', sha1($senha), PDO::PARAM_STR);
#E uso bindValue quando vou passar o valor diretamente na classe pdo como está aqui acima.

#o sha1 vai me retornar um valor, como também poderia usar ex: 12345
$query->bindValue(':pass', 12345, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
#ou assim.
$query->bindValue(':pass', 'senha', PDO::PARAM_STR);


$query->execute();
$dados = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Esse exemplo talvez deixe mais claro como usar, espero que entenda.

Comment: Não está muito claro, `$usuario` não foi definido, será que você esqueceu de adicionar acidentalmente? poderia editar?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o bindParam sempre uso com variaveis se usar uma valor tipo 'nome usuario' no lugar da variável vai dar erro pq ele não aceita valor, e o bindValue é o inverso eu uso o valor mesmo 'nome do usuario' , 1235456, se eu usar uma variavel não teste mas possivelmente retornara um erro pq. Eu entendo assim bindParam parametros por referencia usa variavel, bindValue valores mesmo sem ser por referencia.

Comment: Na verdade eu já sei disto, o que eu quero dizer é que a tua resposta não está "clara", apesar do teu comentário aqui explicar as diferenças, acredito que você deveria ter descrito isto na resposta. Entende?

Comment: Não vejo muita gente comentar aqui sobre o pdo, vejo muito ctr+l ctrl+v e já vi muitas respostas sendo textos da internet e sempre sofri com isso, mas peguei e fui testando e aprendendo com os erros.

Comment: sim sim vou adicionar a respota :)

Comment: Não entendo muito Ctrl+v ? Se tais textos copiados da internet forem em portugues, forem claros e a resposta tiver a fonte original, não vejo problema algum em ser da internet. Veja a resposta do @RowAraujo
não é muito descritiva, mas o exemplo dele explica bem como funciona a referencia, que é um dos motivos do bindParam. Até amanhã!

Comment: entendo mas falei isso no sentido pra meu conhecimento que vi vários repetidos.

Comment: `bindValue()` aceita variáveis também.

Comment: bom saber @rray :)