# Erro quando uso bindParam: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, objetos, passagem-por-referência

Estou recebendo um erro quando uso o [bindParam do PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php), código:

**Classe ConnectionPDO:**

```
function __construct($dsn, $username = NULL, $password = NULL, $options = NULL) {
  parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
  $this->LoadDriverMethods();
}

public function insert($table, $data) {
  $this->lastSQL = $this->driver->insert($table, $data);

  $stmt = $this->prepare($this->lastSQL);

  $this->driver->setParams($this->stmt);

  return $this->stmt;
}

private function LoadDriverMethods(){
  $driver = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'drivers' . 
                      DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'sqldriver.' . 
                      strtolower($this->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME)) . '.php';

  if (!is_file($driver))
     throw new Exception('Não foi possível carregar os métodos do driver', 1);

  require_once $driver;
  $this->driver = new SQLDriver();
}
```

**Classe SQLDriver:**

```
public function setParams(PDOStatement $stmt){
  $params = $this->getParams();
  if (is_array($params) && !empty($params))
     foreach ($params as $param => $value)
     $stmt->bindParam($param, $this->prepareParam($value), $this->getParamType($value));
}
```

Erro:

> Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in \ConnectionPDO\drivers\sqldriver.mysql.php

Que se refere a seguinte linha na classe SQLDriver:

```
$stmt->bindParam($param, $this->prepareParam($value), $this->getParamType($value));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não pode passar valores ou retornos de fuções/métodos para [bindParam()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) pois ele espera referências(variáveis) nesse caso basta trocar por [bindValue()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php).

Vejo que está montando um lib, `bindParam()` só vai fazer diferença no uso de stored procedures que retornam valor, nesse o retorno dela, vai para a variável especificada

Pode montar um bind dinâmico com [essa sugestão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33528/91)

[Qual a diferença entre bindParam e bindValue?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87384/91)

Comment: Valeu, acabei de notar que o problema era no método `bindParam` (o segundo parâmetro é uma referência), tinha trocado a função `$this->prepareParam($value)` por uma variável, mas o bindValue funcionou bem. :D

Comment: @KaduAmaral, está montando um framework?

Comment: Sim rray. Por que?

Comment: @KaduAmaral ta organizado o código :D

Comment: Isso é alguma piada irônica? :v kkkk... Aqui o [link](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/Base).

Comment: Não, serio ta legal o código.

Comment: salvou minha vida :), não sabia desse termo