# Erro: Undefined index: Password in C e erro Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, mysql

erro referente á mesma linha de codigo :

```
$stmt->bindParam(':Password', password_hash($_POST ['Password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
```

Que 
Acumula e regista a informaçaõ inserida no formulario com a seguinte linha

```
<input type="Password" placeholder="Password" name="Password">
```

o Campo Password está tambem corretamente defenido com "P" em MySql.

Bloco completo :

```
if(!empty ($_POST['Username']) && !empty($_POST['Password']));



$sql ="INSERT INTO users (Username,Password) values (:Username, :Password)";
$stmt= $conn->prepare ($sql);
$stmt->bindParam (':Username', $_POST['Username']);
$stmt->bindValue(':Password', password_hash($_POST ['Password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

    if ($stmt-> execute()  ):
        die('success');
        else:  ................
```

Ajuda por favor ?

Comment: sobre o password, edite e ponha a query. Maso o erro é claro, não foi definida uma substituição de bind de nome Password nela.

Comment: veja também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88400/70

Comment: substituir "param" por "value" resolveu o segundo erro. De facto não vejo o que possa estar a causar esse erro, tenho linhas de codigo identicas que estão a funcionar bem. o campo Password para além de estar defenido com pass em vez de texto, tem tem a hash . é a unica diferença..

Comment: Isso é PDO ou mysqli? PDO tem :named, mysqli não.

Comment: PDO. atualizei o codigo em cima

Comment: Separe os conteudos com algo assim: `$hash = password_hash($_POST ['Password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);` e depois `$stmt->bindValue(':Password', $hash );`

Comment: Não resultou =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$email =  $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindParam(':password',$password);
```