# Erro de passagem por referencia, inserir no banco

Tags: php, mysql

Tive os seguintes erros:

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   /var/www/html/crud/banco/Banco.php on line 30
>
> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   /var/www/html/crud/banco/Banco.php on line 31
>
> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   /var/www/html/crud/banco/Banco.php on line 32
>
> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   /var/www/html/crud/banco/Banco.php on line 33

E tenho o seguinte código abaixo, alguém pode me dar uma luz, não é possível fazer desse jeito ?

```
public function insert($table, Post $post){       
    if(empty($table) == false){
        $this->stm = $this->pdo->prepare("insert into ".$table." (titulo, data_criado, corpo, autor) values(?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $this->stm->bindParam(1, $post->getTitulo());
        $this->stm->bindParam(2, $post->getData_criacao());
        $this->stm->bindParam(3, $post->getCorpo());
        $this->stm->bindParam(4, $post->getAutor());

        $this->stm->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: No minimo `insert` está mal escrito na query. Está escrito como `inert`

Comment: já corrigi isso e continua o mesmo erro, sou programador java estou migrando para PHP, é que no java dava para passar um objeto para o método que iria usar o insert, mas aqui PHP não estou conseguindo

Comment: apresenta algum erro

Comment: sim esses ai Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in /var/www/html/crud/banco/Banco.php on line 30

Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in /var/www/html/crud/banco/Banco.php on line 31

Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in /var/www/html/crud/banco/Banco.php on line 32

Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in /var/www/html/crud/banco/Banco.php on line 33

Comment: Veja [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) e [`bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php). O `bindParam` espera uma referência, tal como o próprio *notice* indica.

Comment: coloca o resto do codigo

Comment: só troquei de bindParam para bindValue era isso mesmo muito obrigado, galera valeu a comunidade tá me ajudando muito nessa minha entrada no PHP, obrigadão aeee

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro quando uso bindParam: Only variables should be passed by reference](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88400/erro-quando-uso-bindparam-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Troque 
`$post->getTitulo()`
por uma variável.

Exemplo:
`$titulo = $post->getTitulo();`

Você não pode alterar o valor do que está sendo passado no bindParam, que é o que *$post->getTitulo()* está fazendo.