# Dúvida na segurança do PDO PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença, em nível de segurança, dos dois trechos de código abaixo:

```
// TRECHO 1
<?php
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->bindParam(1, $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(2, $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
?>

// TRECHO 2
<?php
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->execute(array($calories,$colour));
?>
```

No trecho 1, é usado o `bindParam()`, já no 2 os parâmetros são passados diretamente no execute, porem também é usado o `prepare()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em termos de segurança não existe diferença nenhuma. Uma das diferenças é que `bindParam()` além de oferecer a tipagem do parâmetro(`PDO::PARAM_STR`, `PDO::PARAM_INT` etc) tem outros recursos obscuros para o uso de stored procedures. Veja a assinatura do método.

> public bool PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed $parameter , mixed &$variable [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR [, int $length [, mixed $driver_options ]]] )

Ao utilizar o `execute()` todos os parâmetros são enviados como `PDO::PARAM_STR` o maximo que pode acontecer é a sua consulta falhar caso tenha placeholder na clásula `LIMIT/OFFSET`.

**Relacionado:**

[Qual a diferença entre bindParam e bindValue?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87385/91)

[Usar PDO é a maneira mais segura de se conectar a um BD com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68232/91)

Comment: Se eu colocar a tipagem, e passar um parâmetro que não obedeça à mesma, ele converte e executa mesmo assim ou não executa?

Comment: Se você tipar um string como booleano vai funcionar, só vai ter problema no caso que citei na pergunta,  prepared statements são emulados por padrão. @MiguelNeto

Answer (score 3):

Prática e teoricamente não há qualquer diferença, porque se fores analisar, no primeiro caso, onde usaste o `bindParam`, com placeholders do tipo simbólicos (?):

```
$sth->bindParam(1, $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Usaste o número `1` como referência a esse placeholder.

Escrevendo os parâmetros em linha, junto com o método `execute`, não estás a fazer nada de diferente, cada valor recebe índices de acordo com o número de placeholders especificados.

```
$sth->execute( array( 0 => 150, 1 => 'red' ) );
```

Seria o mesmo que fazer:

```
$params = array(150,'red');
$sth->execute($params);
```

Se ainda tiveres dúvidas, recomendo que leias isto:

- [PDO::execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: `$sth->execute( array( 1 => 150, 2 => 'red' ) );` retorna: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined. Se tirar o índice como segundo exemplo ou iniciar em zero ele não ocorre, só `bindValue/Param` precisam iniciar com 1.

Comment: Persisti os índices na edição, era para tê-los removido, para que ficassem normais. O erro SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:, deve-se ao índice 0, assinado como NULL, justamente por causa disso, ou seja, não existe para a array, mas torna-se um valor fictício na execução, quando os parâmetros são dispostos.