# Erro Insert em banco utilizando PDO: "Only variables should be passed by reference"

Tags: php, pdo

Estou passando parâmetros de inserção no banco utilizando PDO e O.O, porem ao dar o comando Insert utilizando os parâmetros `$stm->bindParam(1, $usuario->getnivel());` ele retorna erro dizendo que devo passar somente variáveis para inserção.

Segue código:

```
  public function cadastrar(Cadastro $usuario) {
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO usuarios (nivel,username,senha) VALUES (?,?,?)');   
        $stm->bindParam(1, $usuario->getnivel());
        $stm->bindParam(2, $usuario->getusername());
        $stm->bindParam(3, $usuario->getsenha());
        $stm->execute();
}
```

Comment: Sempre coloque exatamente o erro que aparece, o problema aqui não tinha haver com orientação a objetos ou mysql, no caso o erro é este: *Only variables should be passed by reference*, por favor entenda como uma dica construtiva.

Comment: Ok, obrigado, me atentarei a este detalhe quando possível!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bindParam()` não aceita valores ou retornos de métodos só aceita variáveis ou constantes, nesse caso o melhor é trocar por `bindValue()`

```
$stm->bindValue(1, $usuario->getnivel());
$stm->bindValue(2, $usuario->getusername());
$stm->bindValue(3, $usuario->getsenha());
```

Mais detalhes em: [Qual a diferença entre bindParam e bindValue?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87384/91)

Comment: Obrigado Cara, o bindValue deu certo era somente isso mesmo. Valeeu!