# PDO Statement Dúvidas

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Gostaria de saber se quando eu uso as interrogações para comandos SQL com PDO eu preciso utilizar `bind()`:

```
$SQL->bindValue(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR); // Seria algo assim?
```

Por exemplo nesse caso:

```
$searchSQL = $pdo->prepare('SELECT email,senha FROM tbl_usuario WHERE email = ?');
$searchSQL->execute(array($email));
```

Eu devo inserir aquela linha, antes do `execute()` ou não:

```
  $searchSQL = $pdo->prepare('SELECT email,senha FROM tbl_usuario WHERE email = ?');   
  $searchSQL->bindValue(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR); Eu uso ela?
  $searchSQL->execute(array($email));
```

Porque pesquisando na internet eu vi que posso fazer as consultas SQL usando interrogações ou psedonimos:

```
$searchSQL = $pdo->prepare('SELECT email,senha FROM tbl_usuario WHERE email = ?');
$searchSQL = $pdo->prepare('SELECT email,senha FROM tbl_usuario WHERE email = :email');
```

Mas na videoaula, o rapaz só utiliza `bind()` quando ele usava assim:

```
$searchSQL = $pdo->prepare('SELECT email,senha FROM tbl_usuario WHERE email = :email');
$searchSQL->bindValue(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Algum problema em usar com as interrogações? E aproveitando o tópico, o terceiro parametro `PDO::PARAM`, ele é específico para o tipo da variável?
Para *String* eu uso `PDO::PARAM_STR`, Para *INT* eu `PDO::PARAM_INT` e assim sucessivamente ou não?

Comment: Interrogações são mais interessantes quando você tem condições (geralmente `where`) dinâmicas. No [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68238/91) tem algumas explicações e outros links para partes especificas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente o bind acrescenta uma camada de segurança a mais na hora da consulta, limitando ou excluindo as chances de SQL injections, deve ser usado após o prepare();

No caso de binds com interrogações é recomendável usar a sequência numérica imposta na query SQL exemplo

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tab_usuario where email = ? and senha = ?";
        $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
        $stm->bindValue(1, $email);
        $stm->bindValue(2, $senha);
        $stm->execute();
        $retorno = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); // instancia o resultado em objetos
```

Recomenda-se pseudônimos em consultas do tipo UPDATE e DELETE exemplo

```
$sql = 'DELETE FROM tab_usuario WHERE id_usuario = :id and id_fotos = :id';
        $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
        $stm->bindValue(':id', $id);
        $retorno = $stm->execute();
```

Repare que nesse tipo de query os bind´s não seguem uma ordem cronológica

PDO::PARAM_STR é o 3 parâmetro que o objeto bind por receber como parâmetro, serve para definir o escopo onde cada dado será executado, exemplo strings com vírgulas e inteiros sem vírgulas. lógico que não se julga obrigatório na maioria dos casos

Comment: Que camada de segurança seria essa?

Comment: A forma como o PDO funciona é que ele envia separadamente a instrução (prepare ("INSERT INTO ...)) e os dados.Os dados são enviados separadamente, claramente entendidos como sendo apenas dados e dados.O motor db não tenta mesmo Analisar o conteúdo da seqüência de dados para ver se ele contém instruções, e qualquer código potencialmente prejudicial snipet não é considerado.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: De acordo com a documentação, o método `execute` faz chamadas à `bindValue` e/ou `bindParam` internamente, então esta camada de segurança adicional existirá em ambos os casos. Correto?

Comment: Exatamente, essa camada de segurança é do método bind propriamente dito, execuções internas ou parametrizadas estão a critério do desenvolvedor.

Comment: @FelipeDuarte exatamente "Recomenda-se pseudônimos em consultas do tipo UPDATE e DELETE exemplo", quem recomenda, que seria o sujeito que faz essa recomendação?

Answer (score 3):

Considerando a *query*:

```
SELECT email, senha FROM tbl_usuario WHERE email = ?
```

Utilizar `bindValue`:

```
$searchSQL->bindValue(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Ou passar o valor através de `execute`:

```
$searchSQL->execute(array($email));
```

Tem exatamente o mesmo efeito, visto que a própria [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.execute.php) de `execute` nos fala que é feita a chamada de `bindValue` ou `bindParam` para cada item passado na *array* pelo parâmetro. Isto é, dentro do `execute`, passando o parâmetro, haveria a chamada de:

```
$searchSQL->bindValue(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Portanto, utilizar as duas formas concomitantemente é desnecessário. Porém, é importante salientar que com `execute`, todos os valores serão considerados strings, utilizando o terceiro argumento igual a `PDO::PARAM_STR`. Se por algum motivo precisar de outro tipo de variável, precisará fazer a chamada explícita de `bindValue`.

**Leituras complementares**:

- [Qual a diferença entre bindParam e bindValue?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87384)
- [Qual a vantagem de passar o tipo de parametro no bindValue?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188745/)