# Qual a vantagem de passar o tipo de parametro no bindValue?

Tags: php, pdo, desempenho

Observando a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/188700/14919) desta pergunta, observei que o usuário recomenda passar os parâmetros pela função `bindValue`, indicando o tipo de parâmetro.

Existe [vários tipos](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) de parâmetros que podemos passar, mas os que mais me chamam a atenção são o `PDO::PARAM_STR` e o `PDO::PARAM_INT`.

Por padrão a função `bindValue` sempre utiliza a versão de string.

Ao chegar no banco de dados, o Mysql faz um *typecast* para o tipo correto de dados de acordo com o contexto. Considerando isso

- Vale a pena passar o tipo de parâmetro quando eu for passar um inteiro?
- Desconheço outros mecanismos de banco, existe algum banco que pode apresentar erro por não ser capaz de fazer esse mesmo *typecast* que o Mysql faz?
- E a performance? Sofre algum impacto? No meu entendimento, haverá um typecast no lado do PHP ou no lado do banco, resta saber qual será mais vantajoso.

Comment: Tenho **quase** certeza que é duplicada

Comment: Poderia indicar a pergunta duplicada?

Comment: [Um caso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51712/91) onde o int faz diferença.

Comment: Vinculado: [Qual a diferença entre bindParam e bindValue?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87384/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-bindparam-e-bindvalue)

Comment: @Bonifazio, as perguntas são mesmo muito próximas, mas minha dúvida está mais voltada aos problemas que podem ser causados por não passar o tipo. Por outro lado, a pergunta que o rray colocou me parece responder a esta. Não sei se vale alguem responder minha pergunta ou marcá-la como duplicada.