# É necessário utilizar o terceiro parâmetro do bind*?

Tags: php, pdo

Gostaria de saber se deveria utilizar o terceiro valor do `bindValue()` / `bindParam()`?

Por exemplo:

```
$resultSQL->bindValue(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Ou não há a necessidade de eu usar:

```
$resultSQL->bindValue(1, $email);
```

- Eu deveria utilizar o terceiro parâmetro?
- Exatamente no que e onde ele irá influenciar se eu usar/não usar?

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188745

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51712

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O padrão do 3 parâmetro que é ***opcional*** é `PDO::PARAM_STR` no caso da sua pergunta, não é necessário passar, porque, e-mail já é um dado `string` (***texto***) .

***Sintaxe do código:***

> `public bool PDOStatement::bindValue ( mixed $parameter , mixed $value [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR ] )`

Só é necessário passar o 3 parâmetro, quando o tipo de dado deve ser informado como por exemplo um dado inteiro, um dado boleano, etc. e influência na gravação da informação, um exemplo é gravar uma foto (`array de bytes`) em sua tabela como demostrado logo abaixo:

```
$foto = file_get_contents($foto['tmp_name']);
$stmt->bindParam(':foto', $foto, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
```

***Tipos existentes são:***

- `PDO::PARAM_BOOL`
- `PDO::PARAM_NULL`
- `PDO::PARAM_INT`
- `PDO::PARAM_STR`
- `PDO::PARAM_LOB`
- `PDO::PARAM_STMT`
- `PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT`

Vale lembrar que alguns tipos de dados não existem constante pré definidas, por exemplo, **data**, **data e hora**, **valor monetário**, etc, esses tipos de dados são passados como texto e a conversão é *transparente*, só precisa ser informado o layout que o banco reconhece, um exemplo **data e hora** é `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [PDOStatement::bindValue](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)
- [Constantes pré-definidas](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.constants.php)

Answer (score 3):

Quando usas uma destas constantes no final desse *método*, é o mesmo que aplicar um **filtro de validação**, ou simplesmente tratamento do dado, que transforma o valor num tipo adequado de se armazenar no banco de dados - inserindo aspas, etc.

Embora não tenha critério de obrigatoriedade, é recomendando mesmo quando não se está a usar em programas genéricos - *mais um pouco de segurança e cuidado é sempre melhor que nada, ainda mais quando tens a possibilidade de usar algo assim, perspectivando uma eventual actualização de segurança no software do servidor, ou algo semelhante, tendo apenas algum tempo de digitação como custo, como as actualizações do PHP já por várias provaram, quando vários parâmetros opcionais passaram a ser recomendados/necessários por questões de segurança* -, contudo não deixa de ser opcional.

- se ainda estiver com dúvidas, ou achar que a resposta carece de factos, procura simplesmente no google por *"why use **CONST_NAME** with PDO methods"*, ou algo semelhante em português, ou simplesmente vai vasculhando pelos perguntas antigas aqui existentes relacionados com PDO ou segurança, existem aqui inúmeras perguntas relacionadas, com respostas claras e complexas, e também se não estou em erro, já existe uma pergunta idêntica.

Answer (score 2):

A descrição na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) é:

```
public bool PDOStatement::bindValue ( mixed $parameter , mixed $value [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR ] )
```

Mostrando que é opcional a entrada desse parâmetro. Simplesmente para explicitar o tipo do parâmetro passado.

Um exemplo seria (já implícito a instância do PDO):

```
$id = 4030;
$cartao = "5049.3049";

$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT tbl_cliente.dados_adicionais FROM tbl_cliente WHERE id = :id AND cartao = :cartao");
$sql->bindValue(":id",$id,PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindValue(":cartao",$cartao,PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();
```

Onde:

- O primeiro `BindValue` remete ao ID, vendo como inteiro, sendo referenciado ao `prepare`
- O segundo `BindValue` remete ao cartão de cadastro do cliente, propositalmente dado como número para o exemplo para ser tratado como String no `prepare`.

Comment: Pode exemplificar quando é necessário o uso do parâmetro? Acredito que aumentaria bastante a qualidade da resposta.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Bem lembrado. Editado com exemplo.