# Problema com SELECT e bindParam()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

Ao adicionar o bindParam() após prepara a query, está dando um erro no execute, que diz o seguinte:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\ffpedidos.com.br\sistema\admin\consultas\ff_pedidos_confirmados_consultas.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ffpedidos.com.br\sistema\admin\ff_admin.php(324): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ffpedidos.com.br\sistema\admin\consultas\ff_pedidos_confirmados_consultas.php on line 5

o código do select é o que segue abaixo:

```
  $sql_sel_pedidos = "SELECT pedidos.*, pedidos.valor_recebido AS valorRecebido, clientes.nome AS cliente, entregadores.nome AS entregador, administradores.nome AS administrador, funcionarios.nome AS funcionario, administradores_terceirizados.nome AS admTerceirizada FROM pedidos LEFT JOIN clientes ON clientes.id=pedidos.clientes_id_remetente LEFT JOIN funcionarios ON funcionarios.usuarios_id=pedidos.usuarios_id LEFT JOIN entregadores ON entregadores.id=pedidos.entregadores_id LEFT JOIN administradores ON administradores.usuarios_id=pedidos.usuarios_id LEFT JOIN administradores_terceirizados ON administradores_terceirizados.id = pedidos.administradores_terceirizados_id WHERE pedidos.status = :pedidos.status";
$sql_sel_pedidos_preparado = $conexaobd->prepare($sql_sel_pedidos);
$pedidoStatus = "2";
$sql_sel_pedidos_preparado -> bindParam(':pedidos.status', '2');
$sql_sel_pedidos_preparado ->execute();
```

Comment: retire os espaços na instanciação de bindParam e execute

Comment: `bindParam()` não aceita valores apenas variáveis, o jeito simples de resolver isso é trocar por `bindValue()`. Mais detalhes em: [Qual a diferença entre bindParam e bindValue?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87384/91)

Comment: Está usando o PDO ou MySQLi?

Comment: certo corrigi o problema do bindValue, mas aparece o seguinte erro agora:
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\ffpedidos.com.br\sistema\admin\consultas\ff_pedidos_confirmados_consultas.php on line 6

Comment: Seu bind deve ter apenas letras ou números na consulta mude: `:pedidos.status` para `:status` faça o mesmo no `bindvalue()`

Comment: rray, muito obrigado, funcionou!