# Como obter o numero de linhas de uma instrução SELECT em PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

Como faço para saber a quantidade de registros que me retornaram de uma instrução SELECT? tentei usar o `rowCount()` mas este não funcionou no meu código, quero apenas que me retorne a quantidade só isso.

```
$contador = $this->con->conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE 'usuario' =:usuario AND 'senha' =:senha");
        $contador->bindPARAM(":usuario", $this->usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $contador->bindPARAM(":senha", $this->senha, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $contador->execute();

        echo $contador->rowCount();
```

Comment: $numero = $contador->rowCount();
echo $numero;

Comment: Não deu certo com este código everton ele mostra resultado 0, sendo que no BD consta o usuario e senha.

Comment: Nesse seu caso nem precisa, quantas linhas podem ter com mesmo nome de usuário e senha? Se houver mais de `um` repense sua tabela!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM login WHERE 'usuario' =:usuario AND 'senha' =:senha` -
 Não deveria ser apenas `SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario = :usuario AND senha = :senha`? Ou seja, sem os apóstrofos?

Comment: Tentei assim e também não deu certo SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario =:usuario AND senha =:senha, Eu não sei onde é que estou errando

Comment: faltou o $ nas variaveis WHERE usuario =:$usuario AND senha =:$senha

Comment: Leia esse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87384/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-bindparam-e-bindvalue

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser que ele não esteja entendendo sua requisição, revise a sintaxe SQL só por garantia, se não funcionar tente fazer desta maneira:

```
// Cria objeto PDO
$conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=meuBanco', 'root', 'senhasenha');

// Query que será executada. Recebe o parâmetro :email
$query = "select * from login where usuario= :usuario AND senha = :senha";

// Prepara a query para execução
$consulta = $conexao->prepare($query, array(PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));

// Atribui o parametro $email a :email na consulta
$consulta->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario,':senha',$senha);

// Executa a consulta ao banco de dados
$consulta->execute();

// Conta quantas linhas foram retornadas do banco de dados
$numero_linhas = $consulta->rowCount();
```

Comment: Tentei desta forma e também não deu certo.

public function Entrar($usuario, $senha) {
        if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "botao") === "Funcionario"){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario =:usuario AND senha =:senha";
            $consulta = $this->con->conectar()->prepare($query, array(PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
            $consulta->bindPARAM(":usuario", $this->usuario);
            $consulta->bindPARAM(":senha", $senha);
            $consulta->execute();  
            $num_linhas = $consulta->rowCount();
            echo $num_linhas;

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que `rowCount()` só funciona bem com UPDATE, DELETE e INSERT

No manual >> [**rowCount()**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) - retorna o número de linhas afetadas pela última declaração DELETE, INSERT ou UPDATE executada.

Use PDOStatement :: fetchColumn () para recuperar o número de linhas que serão retornadas.

```
$hostname="localhost";  
$username="USUARIO";  
$password="SENHA";  
$db = "NOME_DB";  
$conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);

$nRows = $conexao->query("select count(*) from login where usuario='$usuario' and senha='$senha'")->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo usando o fetchColunm, eu já não sei mais onde procurar na internet como obter o numero de linhas de um SELECT em PDO, não estou usando query uso o prepare e depois executo

Comment: @sol25lua, dá para postar o código que vc usou conforme sugeri na minha resposta, pois aqui eu testei no meu banco e funcionou?

Comment: public function Entrar($usuario, $senha) {
       if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "botao") === "Funcionario"){
            $consulta = $this->con->conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario =:usuario AND senha =:senha")->fetchColunm();
            $consulta->bindPARAM(":usuario", $this->usuario);
            $consulta->bindPARAM(":senha", $this->$senha);
            $consulta->execute();  
            
                  
        }
    }

Comment: Usei desta forma que me sugeriu mas estou usando o prepare e não query

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetchColunm() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Programas_Orientacao_Obj\Casa_Das_Marmitas\Logar.php on line 19

Comment: vc está misturando, faça conforme  os códigos estão nas respostas

Answer (score 0):

Tente desta forma.

```
    $contador = $this->con->conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE 'usuario' = :usuario AND 'senha' = :senha");
    $contador->bindValue(":usuario", $this->usuario);
    $contador->bindValue(":senha", $this->senha);
    $contador->execute();

    $numero = $contador->rowCount();
    echo $numero;
```

Comment: Não deu certo ele não fez a contagem

Comment: Qual o resultado que ele retorna?

Comment: 0 mas tem resultado no banco de dados